# как повысить UDMA5 до UDMA6

Tags: windows

как повысить до UDMA6, в биосе стоит UDMA6, а в винде UDMA5??? шлейфы менял, может кто знает где в реестре прописать UDMA6
    [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

может это из-за ошибок  в смарте, но вроде они не критичные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш диск поддерживает этот стандарт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы работала UDMA6 необходимо сочетание нескольких

- поддержка накопителем
- поддержка контроллером
- поддержка драйвером контроллера в операционной системе
- чтобы в настройках этот режим был включен.

Как я понимаю, UDMA идет как режим совместимости с PATA-интерфейсом. Для SATA этот параметр неактуален.

Comment: материнка и хдд поддерживают дма6, может это из-за ошибок в смарте, но как их обойти?

Comment: У Вас накопитель уже работает за пределами режима UDMA5 aka UDMA-100 (макс. 100МБайт/сек)

Answer (score -1):

Повысить скорость - это купить SSD. Средняя скорость жёсткого диска всё равно очень маленькая и менять шлейфы, сажать на другой порт, копать реестр - не имеет никакого смысла. Даже покупка [велоцераптора](http://www.wdc.com/ru/products/products.aspx?id=20) оправдана только как "я хочу **очень надёжный** винт".